# {nativescript} application error after install buffer

Tags: nativescript

I'm want to using base64url module. When I install it, it's require buffer. So, I'm install buffer from npm. But after add buffer module, my application error with below message.

I'm already install it with `npm install buffer --save`, Please help.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.kcdm/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'from' of function Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  // Common case.
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    if (typ...<omitted>...
}
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js, line: 127, column: 12

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js', line: 127, column: 13
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/views/login/login3.js', line: 6, column: 14
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'global.loadModule', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/globals/globals.js', line: 29, column: 31
    Frame: function:'resolvePageFromEntry', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 79, column: 40
    Frame: function:'Frame.navigate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 165, column: 20
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 690, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 12, column: 25


TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'from' of function Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  // Common case.
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    if (typ...<omitted>...
}
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js', line: 127, column: 13
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/views/login/login3.js', line: 6, column: 14
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'global.loadModule', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/globals/globals.js', line: 29, column: 31
    Frame: function:'resolvePageFromEntry', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 79, column: 40
    Frame: function:'Frame.navigate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 165, column: 20
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 690, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 12, column: 25


TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'from' of function Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  // Common case.
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    if (typ...<omitted>...
}
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js', line: 127, column: 13
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/views/login/login3.js', line: 6, column: 14
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'global.loadModule', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/globals/globals.js', line: 29, column: 31
    Frame: function:'resolvePageFromEntry', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 79, column: 40
    Frame: function:'Frame.navigate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 165, column: 20
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 690, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 12, column: 25


    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'from' of function Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  // Common case.
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    if (typ...<omitted>...
}
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js, line: 127, column: 12

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js', line: 127, column: 13
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/views/login/login3.js', line: 6, column: 14
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'global.loadModule', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/globals/globals.js', line: 29, column: 31
    Frame: function:'resolvePageFromEntry', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 79, column: 40
    Frame: function:'Frame.navigate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 165, column: 20
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 690, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 12, column: 25


TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'from' of function Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  // Common case.
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    if (typ...<omitted>...
}
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js', line: 127, column: 13
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/views/login/login3.js', line: 6, column: 14
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'global.loadModule', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/globals/globals.js', line: 29, column: 31
    Frame: function:'resolvePageFromEntry', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 79, column: 40
    Frame: function:'Frame.navigate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 165, column: 20
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 690, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 12, column: 25


TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'from' of function Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  // Common case.
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    if (typ...<omitted>...
}
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/buffer/index.js', line: 127, column: 13
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/views/login/login3.js', line: 6, column: 14
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'global.loadModule', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/globals/globals.js', line: 29, column: 31
    Frame: function:'resolvePageFromEntry', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 79, column: 40
    Frame: function:'Frame.navigate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 165, column: 20
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 690, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.kcdm/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 12, column: 25
```

Comment: Probably buffer is nodejs part which causes it to be unable to use inside nativescript so you will need to find something else for base64

Comment: i'm update my question. i've missed typo on require syntaks. :)

Comment: if its this package/module `https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer` you won't get it work as it's browser api and in nativescript there is lot of scrapped up from it as its not exists in native languages

Comment: yes, it's `https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer`. i want to implement base64 encode into nativecript because auhtentication into wordpress with rest api using base64. is there any option for base64 on nativescript?

Comment: to get the bytes from string you could use following construction `var javaString = new java.lang.String("admin:12345");
    var encodedString = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(javaString.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);` Regarding to that in case you are using typescript, you should add `tns-platform-declarations` in your project. For further help, how to do that, you could review this thread in GitHub - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2541#issuecomment-251056341

Comment: many thanks @NikolayTsonev, yours answer enlightening me :)